# Excel: Remove Duplicate Table Filters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel spreadsheet in which I have created a table.  I have a heading called "Location" which I have applied filters to.  When I click the checkbox on this heading which allows me to apply filters I notice I have *two* values of "South Pavillion".  How do I fix so there is only one?

Please take a look at the screenshot [image: here]:

In the filters drop down menu (which I have not provided a screenshot of) South Pavillion is shown twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the values are identical? There could be a trailing space or something that makes them unique. Try to make sure they are indeed identical by using a comparison formula on those 2 cells containing "South Pavilion":

```
=A1=A2
```

It should return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge (which to you is meaningless), I don't think that's possible.  I think all filters need to be managed manually.